# Get a specific value from each object declarative pipeline

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

Hey I have the following json:

```
{
"office365_webhook" : "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/9ecc3795-1a28-4356-a95b-a7802089b426@c659fda3-cf53-44ad-befe-776ee475dcf5/JenkinsCI/bb0f64777e534f1ab2e67085f8ba3b05/e4fa750b-d1d1-426b-a4bc-fe5929eecfe7",
"VRA_IntegrationAws_pipeline" : {
    "MODE" : "full",
    "webhookName" : "datapath build CI",
    "node" : "VraIntegrationAws"
},
"VRA_IntegrationAzure_pipeline" : {
    "MODE" : "azureFull",
    "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
    "node" : "VraIntegrationAzure"
},
"VRA_IntegrationDSS_pipeline" : {
    "MODE" : "dss",
    "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
    "node" : "VraIntegrationDSS"
},
"VRA_IntegrationFromAws_pipeline" : {
    "MODE" : "fromAwsFull",
    "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
    "node" : "VraIntegrationFromAws"
},
"VRA_IntegrationFromAzure_pipeline" : {
    "MODE" : "fromAzureFull",
    "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
    "node" : "VraIntegrationFromAzure"
},
"VRA_IntegrationVmware_pipeline" : { 
    "MODE" : "full",
    "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
    "node" : "VraIntegrationVmware"
},
"VRA_IntegrationPrivate_pipeline" : {
    "modeOptions" : "full\nazureFull\ndss\nfromAwsFull\nfromAzureFull",
    "modeDescription" : "full - toAws and Vmware | azureFull - toAzure | dss - DSS | fromAwsFull - fromAws | fromAzureFull - fromAzure",
    "node" : "VraIntegration15"
    // "node" : "VraIntegration8"
  }
}
```

I want to get all the modes from each object, and use it as a generic choice parameter for a job in jenkins, is it possible?

if so, how can I get all the modes from each object?
how can I load it when trying to build a job?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        JSON = """{
            "VRA_IntegrationAws_pipeline" : {
                "MODE" : "full",
                "webhookName" : "datapath build CI",
                "node" : "VraIntegrationAws"
            },
            "VRA_IntegrationAzure_pipeline" : {
                 "MODE" : "azureFull",
                 "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
                 "node" : "VraIntegrationAzure"
            },
            "VRA_IntegrationDSS_pipeline" : {
                 "MODE" : "dss",
                 "webhookName" : "Datapath guild Teams connector",
                 "node" : "VraIntegrationDSS"
            }
         }
        """
    }

    stages{
         stage("Stage"){
            steps{
                script{
                    def data = readJSON text: json
            
                    println data.collect { _, pipeline -> pipeline.MODE }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could might need to filter out elements like `office365_webhook`. Without details on how it does not work I cannot help you further.